# Access is denied. 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) when looking for COM Ports

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port, wmi, user-permissions

We have run into a situation where some user accounts on a small number of PCs are getting:

> Access is denied: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

when trying to get to a portion of the application that is looking for the COM port that has a barcode scanner attached to it.
I'm thinking it's breaking in one of the following sections of code:

```vb
Public Shared Function ProcessConnectionOptions() As ConnectionOptions
    Dim options As New ConnectionOptions()
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.[Default]
    options.EnablePrivileges = True
    Return options
End Function
```

OR

```vb
Public Shared Function ConnectionScope(ByVal machineName As String, ByVal options As ConnectionOptions, ByVal path As String) As ManagementScope
    Dim connectScope As New ManagementScope()

    connectScope.Path = New ManagementPath("\\" & machineName & path)
    connectScope.Options = options
    connectScope.Connect()
    Return connectScope
End Function
```

OR

```vb
Dim options As ConnectionOptions = ProcessConnection.ProcessConnectionOptions()
Dim connectionScope As ManagementScope = ProcessConnection.ConnectionScope(Environment.MachineName, options, "\root\CIMV2")

Dim objectQuery As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0")
Dim comPortSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(connectionScope, objectQuery)
```

Is there a particular permission that a specific user account has to have in order to be able to access the COM ports on a PC?

Comment: Since your looking for COM (serial ports), why parsing the whole domain of devices in the system? Use the `Win32_SerialPort` class to get informations on serial ports. The `ConfigManagerErrorCode` property is common to all the entities. BTW, I'ld prefer: `Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy`. But the authentican type depends on what machine you're performing the query (local or remote).

Comment: Also, see here: [WMI Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/wmi-troubleshooting) and [Securing a Remote WMI Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/securing-a-remote-wmi-connection).

Comment: Is Windows 10 more strict about a process looking up Win32_PnpEntity?  Is there a security setting that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: Something you have not specified: are you querying the resource of a Local or Remote machine? About the `Win32_PnpEntity`: it's not clear why you're parsing everything non-legacy. Is `Win32_SerialPort` failing to return the desidered result? Yes, you can have access violation for some PnpEntities, Windows 7 included (machine-dependant, not all machines have the same hardware). You need to be prepared for that.

Comment: It's a Windows application querying the resources of the machine it is installed on.

Comment: All right. What about the `Win32_SerialPort` class?

Comment: Unfortunately the scanner isn't activating when I query Win32_SerialPort.  As best as I can tell, the error is coming from the following line:  Dim connectionScope As ManagementScope = ProcessConnection.ConnectionScope(Environment.MachineName, options, "\root\CIMV2")  What sort of permission needs to be added for a user on a PC so they don't get the AccessDenied error?